# PowerShell, how to hold object name as a string

Tags: powershell

I have a yml file that map my VMs lab (below an example of the lab.yml):

```
root:
  apps:
   - app:
      ip: 
      fqdn:
  dbs:
   - db:
      ip:
      fqdn:
```

I read the the following file like that:

```
$lab = Get-Content "C:\lab.yml" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Yaml
```

I can drill down now like that:

```
$lab.root.apps
```

I want to have a variable $var that will hold the following value, for example: 
If the object is `$lab.root.apps`, printing `$var` will displayed `"apps"`
If the object is `$lab.root`, printing `$var` will displayed `"root"`
If the object is `$lab.root.dbs.db`, printing $var will displayed `"db"`
and so on...
I tried different ways (such as `Select-Object`) but it prints the children instead the parent itself

In fact, I want to take the object name and use it in an `if` statement like that:

```
if ($var -eq "apps")
{
  //TO-DO
}
elseif ($var -eq "dbs")
{
  //TO-DO
}
```

Comment: Have you explored [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.1)?

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried. For me it is not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, yes - I got the children. But I don't know how to get the parent name itself

Comment: @zett42 done. Tell me if more code is needed.

Comment: So you are doing something like `$var = $lab.root.apps` and later you want to know if `$var` points to "apps" or whatever?

Comment: @zett42 exactly. But instead to hold the whole info of `$lab.root.apps` i want just `$var` to hold a `"apps"` string inside... (there is an option to add additional property like type: app to each object in dictionary of the yml file - but it seems to be unnecessary if I already have groups in this dictionary)

Comment: If you are actively typing in `.apps`, just do `$var = 'apps'`. If you want to add properties to an object, look at [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7.1). This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @AdminOfThings I can't. I pass the $lab.root.apps as a parameter in a function. inside of the function I need to process it in a way that I can compare it as I shown in the post. I can not do `if ($var -eq $var.root.app)` - it is not working - the script never get inside this condition it is always get `false` even if it really `true`

Comment: @Hiddai Do you have access to edit how said function is coded? If so, you can do something like the following, which i don't recommend anyway -> `function foo { param ([string]$MyParam) $MyParam -replace '.*\.'; $executioncontext.invokecommand.invokescript($MyParam) }`. Now you can call it `foo '$lab.root.apps'`. This makes some assumptions that the function is called as a child scope of the session.

Comment: You could add a property that contains the name, e. g. `$var | Add-Member @{ name='apps' }`. Then within your function you could do `if($var.name -eq 'apps')`. You could even write a function that gets a member of `$lab` by name and adds the property 'name' in one go.

Comment: Which library are you using for `ConvertFrom-Yaml`? I'm asking because if it outputs a `PSCustomObject`, there could be an easier way.

Comment: @zett42 I used: `Install-Module powershell-yaml` (it was taken from PowerShell Gallery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConvertFrom-Yaml` outputs a `hashtable`. In a `hashtable`, objects don't know their name (unlike nodes in an XML DOM) so you have to store the name along with the object. This could be done using `Select-Object` as in the following example.

```
# $var will be a [PSCustomObject] with the single property 'apps'
$var = $lab.root | Select-Object apps

# Now we can get the object name like this:
$var.psobject.Properties.Name   # -> outputs 'apps'

# We can get the actual 'apps' object like this:
$var.psobject.Properties.Value
```

Having to write `$var.psobject.Properties` everytime might be a bit verbose.
You could make things easier by writing a helper function to create your own `[PSCustomObject]`:

```
Function Get-PropertyWithName( $obj, $propertyName ) {
    # As we are not assigning the object to a variable, it is the implicit output 
    # of this function.
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        name = $propertyName
        value = $obj.$propertyName 
    }
}

# Store name and value of property in $var
$var = Get-PropertyWithName $lab.root apps

# Now we can get the object name like this:
$var.name

# We can get the actual 'apps' object like this:
$var.value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you want you can take the properties from different areas of $lab object and place them into a custom object.

```
$var = [pscustomobject]@{
    apps = $lab.root.apps
    root = $lab.root
    db   = $lab.root.dbs.db
    # and so on...
}

$var.apps  # displays "apps"
$var.root  # displays "root"
$var.db    # displays "db"
```